# Редирект изображений на другой домен

Tags: nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить 301 редирект для изображений с одного домена на другой.
Например:
https://site1.com/uploads/posts/image.jpg
на
https://site2.com/uploads/posts/image.jpg

Все изображения будут находится в папке /uploads/, в которой могут быть различные папки.

Пробовал сделать редирект в файле .htaccess, но он не работает. Скорее всего из-за того что статические файлы обрабатываются через nginx. В конфигурационном файле прописывал правило, но оно не работает:

```
location /uploads/ {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://site2.com/$1 redirect;
}
```

Операционная система: Debian 10

Comment: И что не работает?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Не работает редирект. Если вы про правило в .htaccess. Это правило следующее RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ https://www.site2.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг nginx.

Comment: https://github.com/vagordienko/ngnix/blob/c98335fe61df309134363ad9c2a29dff3d557950/n.conf

Comment: Разобрался почему не работал редирект ngnix. Нужно было вставить в секцию с https протоколом. Сейчас работает. Только проблема в том, что редирект 302, а нужно 301. Пробовал вместо "rewrite ^(.*)$" использовать "return 301" - редиректит просто на основной домен, а нужно чтобы был редирект на конкретное изображение

Comment: для 301 редиректа используйте permanent вместо redirect

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас ваши изображения обрабатываются в `location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$`

Поместите внутрь обеих блоков server следующий блок:

```
location ^~ /uploads/ {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://site2.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Указанные инструкции будут перенаправлять запросы, Url которых начинается с `/uploads` на домен site2.com, а остальные изображения будут обрабатываться прежним `location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся. Получилось решить данную задачу. Этот комментарий с решением оставляю, может быть кому-то пригодится.

Для настройки редиректа изображений с одного домена на другой в первую очередь следует понять, кто обрабатывает статические файлы (изображения и т.п.). Если ngnix, то правила в .htaccess не будут работать.

Чтобы настроить редирект нужно прописать следующие строчки в конфигурационном файле ngnix конкретного домена (с которого нужен редирект):

```
location /dir/ {
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

где:

- /dir/ - папка изображений в которой находятся изображения (в том числе будет работать и с вложенными подпапками, то есть не нужно перечислять все вложенные подпапки)
- domain.com - домен на который нужен редирект

По поводу использования rewrite или return. Вот что пишут на просторах Интернета:

> return предпочтительнее rewrite потому, что rewrite требует интерпретации регулярного выражения — ^(.*)$ — и создания пользовательской переменной ($1) , что на самом деле эквивалентно встроенной переменной $request_uri

Я использовал конструкцию "return 301", благодаря которой нет никаких промежуточных редиректов.